# Introduction to Responsa Literature

Tags: torah-study, jewish-books, responsa

I haven't spent much time studying Responsa Literature. Which works would serve as a good introduction? Which respona are essential to a good personal learning program?

Comment: Learning responsa straight in order is generally a very advanced method. Most responsa assume at least basic familiarity with the topic under discussion so unless one is familiar with very many topics, one usually will only check out lists of select responsa related to whatever topic one is currently studying.

Comment: Can you recommend Responsa related to topics covered in Mesachet Berachot? That's what I'm learning at the moment.

Comment: https://hebrewbooks.org/4285

Comment: An interesting read "Reponsa Anthology " Rabbi Avrahom Yaakov Finkel

Answer (score 2):

Based on your question, it sounds like you would appreciate some halachic works that bring and reference various responsa on the topic. I can recommend the following for Masechet Berachot, which you mentioned that you were studying.

On Orach Chaim, where most of the laws in Masechet Berachot can be found there are two very valuable collections of responsa. The first is [Sha'arei Teshuvah](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hayyim_Mordecai_Margolioth), which is printed in standard Shulchan Aruch/Mishnah Berurah books. The second is Piskei Teshuvot, which is a separate work. Both collect important responsa related to the topic at hand, and either summarize or reference various responsa. Piskei Teshuvot is more recent, and often brings very recent authorities on modern-day issues, and is extremely thorough. Sha'arei Teshuvah is much shorter, and generally brings responsa from 200-400 years ago, and many times brings those which relate to kabbalah.

There are other similar works on other areas of halacha (such as pesakim uteshuvot, pitchei teshuvah, etc.). The Bar Ilan responsa project also has a nice selection of responsa related to certain topics, although those are generally from fairly recent authorities as well. Also, many early responsa (such as those of the Rishonim) are brought by other broader halachic works, such as Beit Yosef.  Hope this is helpful!

Comment: This is very helpful. Thank you!

Comment: @Bs234570 if you feel that it answers your question well, you can also mark it as accepted using the green chevk mark.

Comment: Many prints of responsa have indices in the back that did help

Answer (score 1):

There is [a two volume work](https://www.google.com/books/edition/_/iUgwAAAAYAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=0&kptab=overview) by [Solomon B. Freehof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solomon_Freehof) that may be useful in this regard.

Volume I is *The Responsa Literature* and is essentially an introduction to responsa literature. Topics include:

- Origins and Development of the Responsa
- The Leading Respondents
- A Selection of Responsa
- Widespread Debate
- History in the Responsa
- Modern Inventions
- Curious Responsa
- Prospective Development of the Responsa Literature

Volume II is *A Treasury of Responsa* which consists of 63 fully translated responsa, spanning 1,000+ years of responsa writing, by 63 of the most prominent respondents in Jewish history.

Comment: Hi Alex, your suggestion is perfect. Do you happen to know if it's still in print?

Comment: I don’t think so.@Bs234570

Comment: @Bs234570 https://www.ebay.com/itm/394002152455 or https://www.ebay.com/itm/373923119470 or https://www.ebay.com/itm/194760513752